# Get object from array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

I Have this array:

```
 var arrayExample = [
{productId: 1, quantity: 2, name: example, description: example}, 
{productId: 1, quantity: 2, name: example, description: example}, 
{productId: 1, quantity: 2, name: example, description: example}, 
{productId: 1, quantity: 2, name: example, description: example}];
```

My question is

How do I get all the items of the array but taking in every object only the **productId** and **quantity**?
Thus having an array that contains all the objects but only with the two values?
The number of the objects of the array is variable

**Result:**

```
var arrayExampleNew = [
{productId: 1, quantity: 2}, 
{productId: 1, quantity: 2}, 
{productId: 1, quantity: 2}, 
{productId: 1, quantity: 2}];
```

sorry for my English

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just map it

```js
var arrayExample = [{
  productId: 1,
  quantity: 2,
  name: 'example',
  description: 'example'
}, {
  productId: 1,
  quantity: 2,
  name: 'example',
  description: 'example'
}, {
  productId: 1,
  quantity: 2,
  name: 'example',
  description: 'example'
}, {
  productId: 1,
  quantity: 2,
  name: 'example',
  description: 'example'
}];

var arr = arrayExample.map(function(item) {
    return {productId : item.productId, quantity : item.quantity }
});

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

ES2015:

```
const arrayExampleNew = arrayExample.map(({productId, quantity}) => ({productId, quantity}));
```